# Asymptotic normality and normalization wrt variance

Tags: maximum-likelihood, convergence, asymptotics

Let $X_n, n \in \mathbb N$ be a sequence of random variables with finite variances. As $n \to \infty$, are the following two equivalent:

- $X_n \to N(0, \sigma^2)$ for some $\sigma^2 \in [0, \infty)$,
- $\frac{X_n}{\sqrt{Var(X_n)}} \to N(0,1)$?

**Motivation of my question:**

[The asymptotic normality of MLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood#Asymptotic_normality) is usually given with its asymptotic variance being inverse of Fisher information under some regularity conditions:
$$
    \sqrt{n}\big(\hat\theta_\mathrm{mle} - \theta_0\big)\ \xrightarrow{d}\ \mathcal{N}(0,\,I^{-1}(\theta_0)). 
$$

[All of Statistics](http://books.google.com/books?id=th3fbFI1DaMC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA129#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Wasserman, however states 
[image]

I was wondering if the two results (or conclusion parts only) about asymptotic normality of MLE are equivalent?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: One question you might like to ponder is how, if at all,  $I_n(\hat{\theta}_n)$ might relate to $I(\theta_0)$

Comment: @Glen_b: Thanks! If I am correct, $I_n(\hat{θ}_n)$ is still an MLE of $I(θ_0)$, and therefore is consistent, i.e. converges to $I(θ_0)$ in probability.

Comment: @Glen_b: I think I was wrong, it is $I(\hat{\theta}_n)$ not $I_n(\hat{\theta}_n)$  which is still an MLE of $I(θ_0)$, and therefore is consistent, i.e. converges to $I(θ_0)$ in probability.

Answer (score 1):

The two conditions are in general not equivalent. Suppose that
$$ X_n = Z_n + \frac{1}{n}T_n, $$
where $Z_n \sim N(0, 1)$ and $T_n$ is Student-$t$ with 2 degrees of freedom. Then, clearly,
$$ X_n \Rightarrow N(0, 1), $$
meaning that the cdf of $X_n$ converges to $\Phi$. But, the Student-t has infinite variance, and so
$$ Var[X_n] = \infty $$
for all $n$.

Granted, this is something of a pathological example. The "regularity conditions" that Wasserman alludes to are used to ensure that this kind of pathologies don't happen.

Comment: You can still construct similar examples even if the variance of $X_n$ is finite. For example, suppose that $X_n = Z_n$ with probability $(n-1)/n$ and $\pm 1/\sqrt{n}$ with probability $1/n$. Then $X_n \Rightarrow N(0, 1)$, but $X_n/\sqrt{Var[X_n]} \Rightarrow N(0, 0.5^2)$.